# Dash Home won't stop searching/ Can't search in Dash Home

Tags: 14.04, unity-dash, search

I'm running 14.04 and since a couple of days my dash home won't stop searching. Even when the searchbar is empty. It shows a couple of apps and folders, but when I type in a search command nothing happens. I can't seem to find anyone else experiencing this problem. But maybe someone can help.

If you need more info, feel free to ask, see image below for the problem.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this same problem. To fix it, I had to terminate the unity-scope-home and unity-scope-loader processes.

---Instructions---

First, get the process identification numbers for unity-scope-home and unity-scope-loader.

```
pidof unity-scope-home 
pidof unity-scope-loader
```

Then, terminate the processes.

```
kill [PID for unity-scope-home]
kill [PID for unity-scope-loader]
```

And thats it. Searching should work now. Let me know if this works for you and good luck!

Comment: Or just `killall unity-scope-home unity-scope-loader`.